# Where should static objects be constructed in Java?

Tags: java

In the following code, where should sc be constructed?  Without the line "sc = new SClass()", I get a null pointer exception, but I'm not sure if that's the right place for it.  I tried using a static initializer block, but that gave me a compiler error.

Second question is, is there documentation on this type of static intialization?  I could only find references to static primitives, but not static objects.

```
class A {
    private class SClass{
        String s;
        String t;
    }

    private static SClass sc;

    public void StringTest() {
        sc = new SClass();
        sc.s = "StringTest";
        System.out.println(sc.s);
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        a.StringTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's always a good idea to say *which* compiler error you got when you tried the static initializer. Then, we can help with that part of the question.

Comment: It's with Eclipse Helios, Sun JDK 1.6.

Comment: not which compiler, which COMPILER ERROR.

Comment: Sorry, misread that.  When I tried a static initializer with the code above, I got the following error (as noted in my comment below): No enclosing instance of type A is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type A (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of A).  However, the answer from Mark below clarified the problem, and now there's no error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you find you have several things that are static that need some instantiation, or if you have non-trivial work to do, as in this case, you can use a [static initializer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) block, they look something like this:

```
class A {

    static {
        sc = new SClass();
        sc.s = "StringTest";
        System.out.println(sc.s);
    }

    //...
```

You can also define it where you declare it for simpler cases:

```
private static SClass sc = new SClass();
```

Additionally, you have a complicated issue here because you fail to define `SClass` as a static class, but you intend to use it statically. The inner class should have a static qualifier on it, the code below should work:

```
class A {
    private static class SClass{
        String s;
        String t;
    }

    private static SClass sc;

    static {
        sc = new SClass();
        sc.s = "StringTest";
        System.out.println(sc.s);
    }
}
```

Comment: A static block is also good alternative to a static function for more complex initialization of even a single item.

Comment: I tried both approaches, and they give me the following compiler error: No enclosing instance of type A is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type A (e.g. x.new A() where x is an 
 instance of A).

Comment: @suravi: sorry, missed that bit in your question. You can't access a non-static property (the class `SClass`) statically, thus, to use it, you need to define it using the `static` qualifier (see my updated answer for a working sample)

Comment: Mark, thanks for the update, now it works.  In the original code, is it bad form to initialize a static object within an instance method?

Comment: @suravi: yes, it's bad form. static fields belong to the class, not to the instance, so they should be initialized with the class, not with the instance. Use the static initializer block, it's what it's there for.